# Batch file unexpected behavior

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file:

```
for /L %%n in (1,1,10) do (

set a = %%n
echo %%n
echo %a%
)
```

When we run this `%%n` correctly displays as 1,2,3,... 10

But `a` always displays as 10 :   10,10,10,...,10

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion. Inside a FOR or a IF, the variables are "expanded" before and not during command execution. ( expanded = the variable is remplaced by its value )

In order to change the value of a variable and use it in the same loop, you should use the delayed expression.

You must write `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginning of your code and the variable whose expansion should be delayed should be surrounded by exclamation marks instead of percent signs.

So `echo %a%` become `echo !a!`

**EDIT**

Moreover, your `set a = %%n` is invalid since you affect the value of n at the variable "a " and not "a".

you must write `set  a=%%n` ( without a blank space before the equals signe )

Comment: echo !a! just displays !a!

Comment: Problem was with space before a=%%n